# Trying to understand the definition of function field $k(X)$ defined with limit ($X$ is an irreducible variety)

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, definition, limits-colimits

Let $k$ be an algerbaically closed field and $X$ an irreducible variety. 
I want to understand the definition of the function field:
$$
k(X) := \lim_{\substack{ \rightarrow \\ U \not = \emptyset, open }} O_X(U). 
$$

After searching internet, I still don't know what this "limit" means here... Any explanation would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It is the union of all those rings. It is a ring because for $f \in O_X(U),g \in O_X(V)$ then $f+g,fg \in O_X(U \cap V)$. It is a field because the vanishing set of $f$ is closed so $f^{-1} \in O_X(X-Z(f))$. Try with $X = \Bbb{C}$ and $O_X(U)$ the ring of rational functions with no poles on $U$ and $U \ne \emptyset$ open iff $X-U$ is finite.

Comment: Here it means direct limit, or colimit over a directed set

Comment: @reuns I see. How come people just don't write $\bigcup_{U \not = \emptyset, open} O_X(U)$? Is there a difference I need to keep in mind here?

Comment: Can you show how you'd construct $O_X(U)$ for $I$ a prime ideal of $k[t_1,\ldots,t_m]$ and $X = V(I)$ ? The union is well-defined because you have compatible inclusions $O_X(U),O_X(V)$ into $O_X(U \cap V)$ which is the point of the direct limit.

Comment: Abstractly elements in $O_X(U)$ and $O_X(V) $ have no relations. The identification comes from restriction maps. So simply taking the union will give you too many elements as $f\in O_X(U)$ and $g\in O_X(V)$ are distinct elements even if $U\subset V$, you want to identify them as the same when they agree on smaller open sets. So after taking the union, the direct limit is just this union quotient by an equivalent relation.

Comment: It makes sense now! Thank you!